# How do you remove a space before a citation in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, citing

I have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

Blah Blah (\cite{All14})

\bibliography{Ref}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

But LaTeX keeps placing a space before my citation, i.e. my output looks like "Blah Blah ( [All14])". 
So, I modified it to `Blah Blah (\hspace*{-3px}\cite{All14})`.
However, this seems to be a less than elegant solution.  Is there a better way to eliminate this space?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `cite` package tries to be clever and insert spaces before references when they are necessary.  For example if you type

```
Here is some text\cite{xxx}.
```

then it will insert a space after "text".  This behaviour can be turned off completely by

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

Alternatively, if you want this behaviour in general but have problems in isolated cases, you can insert a small space

```
(\hspace{1sp}\cite{All14} says...)
```

`1sp` is the smallest non-zero space in TeX, roughly 1/100 of the wavelength of light according to the TeX book.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

Blah Blah (\hspace{1sp}\cite{All14})

\bibliography{Ref}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Andrew Swann, the `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` works globally to remove spaces before the citations.

But one easy way to set spaces before the citation, even with this parameter set globally, is to use a tilde before the cite:

```
~\cite{All14}
```

This will create the space before the citation, when needed for isolated cases, and still keep the global parameters intact.

P.S. I apologise for this trivial addition to the answer. But I didn't have enough reputation to add a comment to Andrew Swann's already excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, but I believe that the unwanted space is only a minor effect of a wrong approach, so I have also another suggestions:

1. Do not use `cite`. This package is to format numeric citations, so I think that have little utility with an `alpha` style where references are the bibtex keys. Without the package, `(\cite{All14})` will work as expected.
2. Do not use parenthesis. The reference already use brackets as delimiters, so a additional delimitation is completely superfluous.
3. OK, for some odd reason you need `cite` and references with double delimiters. In this case the delimiter format is controlled by `\citeleft` and `\citeright`. So, to obtain what you want you can use `\renewcommand\citeleft{([}` and  `\renewcommand\citeright{])}`, so you only have to use `\cite{All14}` to have `([All14])`.

Besides, a little (opinion-based) comment: If possible, avoid bibkeys as references. It is not inelegant, but the next.

Comment: Could you explain the "avoid bibkeys as references" please?

Comment: @AJP I mean the usual in formal texts is reference a paper with a number (e.g.: `[23]`) or the author and year (e.g.: `(Smith, 1981)`), but if the citation simply show the bib key (e.g.: `[Smith81]` or  `[All14]` is  odd in most fields.